# 410 Gone error in MSGraph Delta API for oneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using `/delta` OneDrive APIs from Graph to sync files & folders for all the users in my organization.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0):

> There may be cases when the service can't provide a list of changes for a given token (for example, if a client tries to reuse an old token after being disconnected for a long time, or if server state has changed and a new token is required). In these cases, the service will return an HTTP 410 Gone error

There is no exact time-frame when the delta token is too old or expires.

Is there a particular time-frame after which the token is unusable in case of drive and we'll get the `410` error?

Answer (score 0):

There is not defined time to live (TTL) for delta tokens, nor is the age the only factor in determining if the token is invalid. If there are substantial changes (i.e. substantial changes to the tenant and/or drive could cause it as well).

So long as your code is set up to handle a possible `410`, you shouldn't see much impact from this. My general guidance would be to optimize for a "full resync" but comparing file metadata and only pulling or pushing files that have changed (i.e. compare name, path, size, dates, etc.).

Comment: How I can do "full-resync"? What do you mean?